# Why can't I access this instance variable using the combination constructor/prototype pattern?

Tags: javascript

I apologise for such a simple question - I'm new to JS, though I thought I understand this pattern (combination constructor/prototype).

In my code (snippet below), my prototype methods for my "Journal" type cannot read instance properties of objects of journal type. But my other types work fine, and I can't see the difference between my journal type and my other types.

Clicking on my save button (invoking updateEntry method, code below) gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Here is the relevant JavaScript -

```
var Journal = function(saveBtn) {
    this.entries = [];

    this.saveBtn = document.getElementById(saveBtn);
    this.saveBtn.onclick = this.updateEntry;
};

Journal.prototype.updateEntry = function() {
    console.log('Let\'s see if entries accessible: ' + this.entries.length);
};

var journal = new Journal('btn');
```

Why can journal's invocation of Journal.prototype.updateEntry() not view journal.entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is being called with the DOM element `saveBtn` as `this`, instead of the `Journal` object.

Do this instead:

```
this.saveBtn.onclick = this.updateEntry.bind(this);
```

or if using IE8 or below,

```
var self = this;
this.saveBtn.onclick = function() { self.updateEntry(); };
```

Explanation:

When the click happens, the follow is being called:

```
saveBtn.onclick();
```

Thus `saveBtn` is the `this` in the function. `bind` (or the `self` variable) make sure that the this in the context of `Journal` is retained, no matter on what object the function is being called.

Comment: @jpau: `addEventListener` should exhibit the same problem. It doesn't matter which method you use to bind the event handler. If the function isn't bound, `this` will always refer to the DOM element the handler is assigned to.

Comment: You're correct. Thanks Felix. Thanks Paul.